# Changing icons' size only in subfolders (Windows 10) - Software collateral effect

Tags: windows, windows-10, user-folders

Today I used a new software (W7FBC) to change the background of a folder. After I use it, the icons in subfolders got smaller.

Is it possible to change the icons' size only in subfolders? I'm using Windows 10.

---

EDIT: now the icons of subfolders have the following size:

[image]

before the use of the software (W7FBC), the icons in the subfolders had the same size of the icons on the left in figure: Accesso rapido, Download etc.

Moreover, I noted that, when I open a folder for the first time (after restart of PC), the long names of subfolders are visualized only partially. If a click on update, the names are completely visualized.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: "Is it possible to change the icons' size only in subfolders?" – It did happen to you, right? So it is possible. Maybe the question should be "how to revert?" But frankly I cannot tell for sure if the icons of objects on the left are larger than others; their vertical spacing is.

Comment: Hello @KamiiMaciorowski, my goal is to restore the default settings.

Comment: Press Ctrl+Shift+1 to 8 in File Explorer until you're satisfied :)

Comment: Hello @Biswapriyo, I know it. The problem is another: I want to "zoom" a bit the subfolders in figure. Tell me how many subfolders there may be in a single column on your Windows 10 please. In this way we can compare the number to understand if in my case there was a zoom minus. On my Windows 10, in a column there are 41 subfolders.

Comment: Depends on monitor size.

Comment: @Biswapriyo, my monitor is 15.6 and I set a resolution of 1920x1080.